# How many standard profiles do we have in salesforce?

Tags: profile, user-management

Hi I have a developer org and in that I have observed different set of 18 standard profiles while http://ap1.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/standard_profiles.htm link demonstrated another set of 18 profiles.I'm confused totally,Please help with the correct number of standard profiles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the standard profiles out of box from salesforce do not have the custom flag checked. Any profile you see that are not part of the link you have referred here are custom profiles created by someone who uses your org.

Answer (score 10):

There are six (6) Salesforce standard user profiles. Additional standard profiles will appear when certain conditions are met within an organization, such as enabling Chatter, Partner Portal, Customer Portal, or Sites. The link posted in the original question does not appear to include all possible profiles that are available. For example, there are legacy standard profiles for license types that can no longer be purchased, and there are yet other profiles and license types that are used internally within salesforce.com and are not available to organizations, yet would still count as standard profiles. The actual list of standard profiles probably exceeds 40.

Answer (score 9):

Standard Profiles which mostly used are:

- System Administrator
- Standard User
- Read Only
- Solution Manager
- Marketing User
- Contract Manager

A profile of which most of the permissions you can't change are standard profiles.
Profile is standard which have **Custom Profile** label unchecked when you open it.

Also you can differentiate standard and other profile by creating new view in :

Administrator | Manage User | profiles > create new view > Name it and Specify filter criteria by clicking settings > All | custom > then click insert button > not equal to `true` and then save it. Now you can filter using view list in profiles.